# What are the deprecated features in SQL Server 2016? Is MERGE statement available in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
create table #Temp1 (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(50))

insert into #Temp1 values('Gokul')
insert into #Temp1 values('Dhivakar')

create table #Temp2 (id int, name varchar(50))
insert into #Temp2 values(1, 'Srikanth')
insert into #Temp2 values(3, 'Yogish')

select * from #Temp1
select * from #Temp2


MERGE #Temp1 AS target  
    USING #Temp2 AS source 
    ON (target.id = source.id)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE SET Name = source.Name  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (Name)  
    VALUES (source.Name) ; 
   -- OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
```

Comment: If only Microsoft would publish detailed [documentation on SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why don't you just check [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: It's a shame Microsoft haven't provided details on [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017) either. If only there was a [search engine](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=SQL+Server+Deprecated+features+2016) that could be used to try to find such information. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Merge Statement supported in SQL Server 2016. It is supported 2008 onwards.